# Connection refused on API request between containers with docker compose

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm developing a multi-container Docker application and I want a container to make an HTTP request to API of other container using Docker Compose. I'm getting Connection Refused error.

Both containers run ASP.NET Core 2.2.
The IDE I'm using is Visual Studio 2017.
I'm testing API calls with Postman.

Things I've tried:
✔️ Ports are exposed in Dockerfiles 
✔️ Ports are declared in Docker Compose configuration 
✔️ Network is declared in Docker Compose and containers are connected to it 
✔️ Http request URI uses service name and not *localhost* or local IP address 
✔️ Http request URI uses container port (80) and not host port 
✔️ Firewall is disabled 
✔️ Custom network with custom subnet 
✔️ Custom IPv4 address for services 
✔️ Docker Compose downgraded to v2.4 (to specify gateway on custom networks) 
✔️ Delete and recreate serviceB project 
✔️ Switched from basic usage of HttpClient to typed clients (custom services) 
✔️ Switched from GetAsync(Uri) to GetAsync(Uri,HttpCompletionOption,CancellationToken)

Dockerfiles

```hs
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
```

Docker Compose configuration:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  servicea:
    ...
    ports:
      - "51841:80"
      - "44364:443"
    networks:
      - local

  serviceb:
      ...
    ports:
      - "65112:80"
      - "44359:443"
    networks:
      - local

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

serviceA controller action:

```
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult foo()
{
   HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

   var result = client.GetAsync("http://serviceb:80/api/bar").Result;
   var response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

   return new OkObjectResult(response);
}
```

If I do an Http Get request to serviceA (with host port 51841) with Postman at `http://localhost:51841/api/foo` I'd like to get the response of serviceB's Bar action.

But I'm getting Connection refused

Raw exception details:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

**PING**

If I access to serviceA's bash and do ping to serviceB (and specifically serviceB's :80 port) it works:

```sh
root@serviceA_id:/app# ping -p 80 serviceb
PATTERN: 0x80
PING serviceb(10.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ... (10.168.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from ... (10.168.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.101 ms
64 bytes from ... (10.168.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
--- serviceb ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2057ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.083/0.100/0.117/0.016 ms
```

**CURL**

I can also stablish connection with API REST endpoint with CURL but Content-Length recieved is 0

```sh
root@serviceA_id:/app# curl -v http://serviceb/api/bar
*   Trying 10.168.0.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serviceb (10.168.0.3) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/bar/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: serviceb
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 07:11:31 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://serviceb:44359/api/bar/
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host serviceb left intact
```

So we can see serviceB is telling serviceA that its request will be redirected to `https://serviceb:44359/api/bar/` but the desired connection port is 80 (container port), not 44359 (host port)

If I let curl follow redirections then Connection Refused appears (the redirected port is closed)

```sh
root@serviceA_id:/app# curl -v -L http://serviceb/api/bar
*   Trying 10.168.0.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serviceb (10.168.0.3) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: serviceb
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 08:48:33 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://serviceb:44359/api/bar
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host serviceb left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://serviceb:44359/api/bar'
*   Trying 10.168.0.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.168.0.3 port 44359 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to serviceb port 44359: Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to serviceb port 44359: Connection refused
```

**Why I am being redirected to host port?**

In `Startup.cs` my services were using `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` so removing that line solved the problem

**What if I still need to use HTTPS?**
Add option to use container port. More info in answer

Comment: +1m Thanks so much, i've been tweaking my docker-compose for days trying to get past this connection refused error!

Comment: I got the Connection Refused error and landed on your question. Went through your checklist and realized I hadn't exposed this new port, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to the question - but - please, dont use .Result on your async method calls, use await - its bad practise and you're setting yourself up for all sorts of problems ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ServiceA's HTTP requests were being redirected (HTTP 307 status code) to `https://serviceb:44359/api/bar` being `:44359` the host port for HTTPS. Host ports are not accessible between containers, container ports do. So if I access to serviceA's terminal and send an HTTP request with `curl` verbose `-v` following redirections `-L` to the URI `http://serviceb/api/bar` I got the Connection Refused error:

```sh
root@serviceA_id:/app# curl -v -L http://serviceb/api/bar
*   Trying 10.168.0.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serviceb (10.168.0.3) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: serviceb
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 08:48:33 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: https://serviceb:44359/api/bar
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host serviceb left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://serviceb:44359/api/bar'
*   Trying 10.168.0.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.168.0.3 port 44359 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to serviceb port 44359: Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to serviceb port 44359: Connection refused
```

**Why I were being redirected to host port?**

In `Startup.cs` my services were using `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, that line was causing the problem.

The default configuration of [HttpsPolicyBuilderExtensions.UseHttpsRedirection(IApplicationBuilder) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.httpspolicybuilderextensions.usehttpsredirection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.HttpsPolicyBuilderExtensions.UseHttpsRedirection);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.2) redirects to HTTPS host port by default. If you want to use a different port for redirection you need to add that option so `Startup.cs` will look like this:

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            ...

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.HttpsPort = 443;
            });

            ...

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            ...

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            ...

        }
    }
```

Comment: Mate! you are an angel.

Answer (score 1):

> but it doesn't when I do ping to serviceB's API REST:
>
> ```
> root@serviceA_id:/app# ping -p 80 serviceb/api/bar
> PATTERN: 0x80
> ping: serviceb/api/bar: Temporary failure in name resolution
> ```
>
> That may be the cause of Connection Refused error when doing API
>   requests from ASP.NET

That's not how ping works. Ping uses ICMP, not TCP, and not HTTP which works on top of TCP. You ping a host, not a TCP port or HTTP API. So the above is expected to fail.

> I can also stablish connection with API REST endpoint with CURL but
>   Content-Length recieved is 0
>
> ```
> root@serviceA_id:/app# curl -v http://serviceb/api/bar
> *   Trying 10.168.0.3...
> * TCP_NODELAY set
> * Connected to serviceb (10.168.0.3) port 80 (#0)
> ```

This indicates you have correctly configured docker containers to communicate, there's nothing more to debug in the configuration of your networks, and you know your serviceb is is listening.

The only things left to debug are:

- Make sure servicea is connecting to serviceb on port 80, not 65112 or any other host port. Containers communicate between each other on container ports.
- Make sure you are running the code posted, and not a previous version. This is easy to mistake when building and deploying images, especially if you aren't changing your image tag for each build.
- Make sure you give serviceb time to start. I've often seen these errors when servicea starts before serviceb.

If you still have issues, you can start debugging with tools like tcpdump. E.g.

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:$container_id \
  nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -i any port 80
```

Replace the `$container_id` with the id of serviceb to see any TCP requests to port 80 on that container.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I used curl so I could get a lighter output and kept focused on following the evolution of the HTTP requests and that helped me to find the solution, so yes I was trying to connecto to the right port but I were being redirected to a wrong port. Your 1st suggestion was correct

Comment: "Containers communicate between each other on container ports" - this was my mistake.

Answer (score -2):

You have to specify the port also when connecting from the same docker network:

```
var result = client.GetAsync("http://serviceb:80/api/actioname").Result;
```

Comment: I tried but same error. As far as I'm concerned specifying port in URI is not needed when you're accesing :80 (with http scheme) or :443 (with https)

Comment: @JorgeJGonzález that's true. Can you please also try removing `networks ` directives? since it should work by default.

Comment: @JorgeJGonzález please also try using different ports in service B (to not duplicate 80 and 443 in the same network).

Comment: I've removed network directives and its use and I've changed exposed/declared ports from 80 for both services to 80 and 81, but I'm still getting ConnectionRefused error

Answer (score -2):

```
var result = client.GetAsync("http://serviceb:65112/api/actioname").Result;
```

you have exposed port 65112 for service B in docker-compose so use the same port

Comment: I've tried it and I'm still getting the same error, but I think I have to use container ports for container communication instead of host ports